# Using JSON as a datastore with Flask?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a question that I need some opinions on. I have a small JSON file, and I'm using as a datastore.

```
{"stress": [1, "good"], "physical": [6, "ok"], "mood": [8, "good"], "perception": "neutral", "spoons": 74}
```

Basically I have a webhook running in flask on a pi for an alexa service. And throughout the day this datastore is updated. ie: If you go through one intent then it updates stress to 4. This is NOT an application. This is a standalone installation piece that runs locally, in a room, and doesn't need to scale at all.

What's the best way to do this? Should I just store this JSON file in the root folder and import it then write out to it? Should I look at something like tinyDB instead? Should I toss into Flask's static folder?

Again, super tiny thing, doesn't need to scale. Doesn't have multiple users. I feel like something like postgres or a full db is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar... and it's running on an actual production server. However there is never more than 100 users. For your use case, it's fine.

Above my Flask routes, I have two simple functions that read/write from/to the JSON datastore.
I would personally create a separate folder in your application named "datastore" and just leave it in there. Here's a simple example:

```
def write_json(path, json_data):
    with open(path, 'w') as file_out:
        json.dump(json_data, file_out)


def read_json(path):
    with open(path) as file_in:
        return json.load(file_in)


# begin Flask views/routes
@app.route('/user_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def user_form():
    path = "/home/myapp/datastore/store.json"


    # input from form or wherever your new JSON is coming from...
    # It could also be coming from a REST API etc:
    input = request.form['data']
    # {"new": "data"}


    # read in existing JSON
    existing_json = read_json(path)
    # {"existing": "json"}


    # add new JSON to existing JSON however you see fit
    [(k, v)] = input.items()
    existing_json[k] = v
    {"existing": "json", "new": "data"}


    # now update datastore
    write_json(path, existing_json)


    # could also be app.response or jsonify here etc...
    return render_template("success.html")
```

and so on...

Just set the path variable to wherever your file is stored...

So once your code runs and you have a value that is ready to be added to the datastore, call the read function, add your new data to the JSON object, and immediately call the write function to re-write the newly updated JSON back to the same file.